# Get parent and children objects in single ajax response

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, ruby-on-rails-3

This rails app I am working on has the following models:

Albums has_many :tracks

Track belongs_to :album

Part of the app allows me to play an entire album by clicking a link. This fires off an ajax request like so:

```
  $.ajax({
    url: '/albums/' + _this.parent().data("id") + '.json',
    data: { id : _this.parent().data("id") },
    success: function(json) {
      //more code here

    }
  });
```

My controller has this:

```
 def show
  @album = Album.find(params[:id])
  render json: @album
 end
```

This all Works!

My question is, how can I get the album and the tracks that belong to that album in one ajax request?

I tried:

```
 render json: @album.tracks
```

This gives me all the tracks but not the album.

So if there is a way to get both with one request please point me in the right direction.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps if you do this:

```
render json: {'album' => @album, 'tracks' => @album.tracks}
```

Then in your ajax code:

```
success: function(json) {
  //more code here
  json.album contains album info
  json.tracks contains tracks info

}
```

**Edit** This is a cleaner approach in one line:

```
render json: @album.to_json(:include =>  :tracks)
```